# Download source of all dependencies & devDependencies of Node.js module and compile in offline mode

Tags: node.js, npm, compilation, rebuild

I want to download sources of all dependencies and devDependencies of specific Node.js module. After that move all of them to an offline server, then compile and rebuild them.
NOTICE: Online server is Windows and offline server AIX. because of this, I want to move and compile and rebuild the module (the module has C++ code).
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You likely can't. Use VM with the same OS as offline server if you can.

Comment: @estus Thanks for your reply. But I can't server AIX on VM. Are any solutions to solve this?